# Hacer columna ItemID SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 Filas de nombre `Type` y `TypeID` necesito crear una llamada `ItemID`
que el `itemID`  recoja los dígitos de la filas `type` y `TypeID` pero que siempre el `typeID` sea rellenado con ceros en caso que el número sea menor a (100) ejemplo abajo:

Problema

- Si la columna `Type` es 1 y la columna `TypeID` va del 1 al 100
- Si la columna `Type` es 2 y la columna `TypeID` va del 1 al 100
- Si la columna `Type` es 3 y la columna `TypeID` va del 1 al 100
- Si la columna `Type` es 4 y la columna `TypeID` va del 1 al 100

**Ejemplo:**

```
Type TypeID
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    5 sigue hasta el numero 100
1    100
2    1
2    2
2    3
2    4
2    5 sigue hasta el numero 100
2    100
3    1
3    2
3    3
3    4
3    5 sigue hasta el numero 100
3    100
4    1
4    2
4    3
4    4
4    5 sigue hasta el numero 100
4    100
100  1
100  2
100  3
100  4
100  5 sigue hasta el numero 100
100  100
```

Necesito crear una tercera columna llamada `ItemID` que tome el `Type` su número sea 1  `typeID` sea 1  y esta quede así:

Ejemplo A:

```
Type TypeID ItemID
1    1      1001
1    2      1002
1    3      1003
1    4      1004
1    5      1005
1    5      1100
```

Nota: el relleno de dos dígitos faltantes entre `type` y `TypeID` sea rellenado con ceros (0) como muestra el ejemplo A.

Ejemplo de crear una fila a partir de un `type` 200 y `typeID` es 200 sería:

Ejempo B:

```
Type TypeID ItemID
200  201    200201
200  202    200202
200  203    200203
200  204    200204
200  205    200205
200  206    200206
```

Ejemplo B muestra la combinación de dígitos en `type` y `typeID` (Sin relleno de dígitos)

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, no acabo de entender bien del todo lo que quieres porque en ejemplo A no se porque con Type 1 y TypeID 5 en un caso da 1005 y en otro 1100.

Comment: Y una vez que logres agregar la columna con los valores correctos, ¿pueden seguir cambiando `Type` y `TypeID`, agregándose nuevos registros? O sea, ¿es necesario preocuparse por mantener la nueva columna al día con futuros cambios también?

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo correctamente, entonces la columna que quieres sería:

```
SELECT Type,
       TypeID,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Type) + 
       RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),TypeID),3) ItemID
FROM dbo.TuTabla;
```

Comment: Exelente hermano pero como seria en MySQL yo la puse en sql server 2008 R2 pero se me olvido que es para Mysql. y no para SQL server 2008